# In Objective-C, when are metaclass object and class object created?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

In Objective-C, when are the class pairs - metaclass object and class object, created? Is it in the beginning of the app execution or at the point when you first instantiate the first object of a class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the point that the class is added to the class hierarchy. This is generally when the app is launched, but could be later if the class is added by a dynamically loaded library or is created programatically.

The class object and metaclass have to exist at the time that `+load` is called (which is the above).

Comment: Thanks Rob.  So it's before main is called?

Comment: For statically linked classes, yes. It'll also be before C++ initializers in your framework are called. See the docs for +[NSObject load] for the order of things that happen around +load time. Everything listed there is before main().